# Row count column count in all tables in Sybase database

Tags: sql, sybase, sybase-asa

I have a database name ATs . In this database 150 tables. I want to create a statement that return the row count and column count all tables on the database .

I have created a store procedure For SQL SERVER 2008 but i don't know how to write this script for Sybase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase ASA has a bunch of system tables providing you with information about the structure of your database. The two tables that are of interest for you are `SYSTABLE` (all tables) and `SYSCOLUMN` (all columns).

I tried this quick and dirty stored procedure that works for me (on the rather aged ASA version 8!). It creates a temporary table and a cursor to iterate over all tables. For every table the table name, number of columns and number of rows are inserted into the temp table and finally returned.

(Hint: the *tablefilter* allows to return only a subset of the whole database, if you have many tables.)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Usr_TableStats(in par_tablefilter char(100))
RESULT (tablename varchar(255), number_of_cols int, number_of_rows int)
BEGIN

    declare err_notfound exception for sqlstate value '02000';
    declare @table_id  integer;
    declare @tablename varchar(100);
    declare @cols      integer;
    declare @sql       varchar(300);

    declare tables no scroll cursor for select table_id, table_name from sys.systable where table_type = 'BASE' and table_name like par_tablefilter || '%' order by table_name;

    create table #tablestats (
        tablename       varchar(100) not null,
        number_of_cols  int not null default 0,
        number_of_rows  int not null default 0
    );

    open tables;

    LoopTables: loop

        fetch next tables into @table_id, @tablename;

        if sqlstate = err_notfound then
            leave LoopTables
        else
            SELECT COUNT(column_id) INTO @cols FROM SYSCOLUMN WHERE table_id = @table_id;
            set @sql= 'INSERT INTO #tablestats SELECT ''' || @tablename || ''', ' || @cols || ', COUNT(*) FROM ' || @tablename || ';';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE WITH QUOTES @sql;
        end if

    end loop LoopTables;

    close tables;

    SELECT tablename, number_of_cols, number_of_rows FROM #tablestats;

END
```

Call it in iSQL like this:

```
CALL Usr_TableStats('%'); -- all tables
CALL Usr_TableStats('ADDRESS%'); -- only tables starting with ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

sys.systable and sys.syscolumn should provide you with the information:

```
   Select st.table_name, 
    st.count as row_count,
    col_count = (SELECT count(*) FROM sys.syscolumn where table_id = st.table_id)
    from SYS.SYSTABLE st where st.creator <> 0 and st.count > 0
    order by st.table_name
```